# Final Draft alternative that supports Greek

Tags: windows, word-processor, screenwriting

[Final Draft](https://www.finaldraft.com/) does not work with my language (Greek). I am looking for an alternative.

It would be better if it was gratis.

I am using Windows 8.1 but software for previous Windows versions is ok.

Final Draft is software that helps with screenwriting. The features that it has and I need is keeping track of characters appearances, scenes, which characters are in which screen, how often a character appears, what characters I currently have, scene locations, exporting to pdf (which I suppose is a standard with all word processor tools) and if possible text to speech but not necessary.

I do not need collaboration features that it includes.

Also the software must not be web based. I need to be locally available so I can use everywhere I might be (which sometimes is without internet access).